# Xamarin programmatically change Textview.Text to a resource string

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

A simple android app , I tried this code to change a Textview.Text to a string in resources file, and that was my approach :

```
private void BtnClickMe_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        TextView TxtView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);

        TxtView.Text = "@string/SomeWord";
    }
```

any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code,

`text.Text = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.app_name);`